# Pycharm Ipython Console: How can I tell whether the program is finished?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm with Ipython console. Unlike the plain console when the program is running the console is frozen.
When I execute a program, the Ipython console seems return immediately without any sign whether the program is running. How can I tell the program is finished or not?
[image]

The console is frozen so I know the program is still running.

[image]

The ipython console returned immediately.

Thanks!